# Is it possible to count and/or return unique values from an SQL database?

Tags: sql

Lets say I have this table:

```
ID|Username|Mood    |color
-------------------------
1 |User1   |Sad     |red
2 |User1   |Happy   |red
3 |User1   |Mad     |red
4 |User1   |Scared  |green
5 |User1   |Sad     |green
6 |User2   |Sad     |purple
7 |User2   |Happy   |red
8 |User3   |Mad     |blue
9 |User4   |Scared  |green
10|User4   |Sad     |red
```

In the DB I have a total of 4 users: User1, User2, User3, and User4.
is there a SQL statement that could count the number of unique values in a certain column?
Is there a SQL statement that could return these unique values?
so it would return:

```
ID|Unique_Users
----------------
1 |User1
2 |User2
3 |User3
4 |User4
```

If all of my wishes could come true I would like to take it even further, by querying for intersection unique values where both the Username and his mood are unique and get:

```
ID|Username|Mood
-----------------
1 |User1   |Sad
2 |User1   |Happy
3 |User1   |Mad
4 |User1   |Scared
6 |User2   |Sad
7 |User2   |Happy
8 |User3   |Mad
9 |User4   |Scared
10|User4   |Sad
```

(In the original table User1 was sad in indexes 1 and 5, but in the new table, since it is not unique, it is not repeated)

Notes:
1. It is not a matter of checking if the value already exists when I insert into the table because there is additional information (that is not duplicated) in every entry
2. I know I can select all the values, and then process the information to find out the unique values, and run a new query for each unique value getting the rest of the information but this requires server usage and I am trying to make it as efficient as possible.

Comment: Please, format the question. As side note, in your "most expected result" it doesn't make sense for `user2` to have the `id` of `5`, as it belongs to `user1`. `user2` should have both `6` and `7`.

Comment: @MostyMostacho, Thanks, didn't notice it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a simple group by:

```
SELECT MIN(id), username, mood FROM table
GROUP BY username, mood
```

Now, note this won't return `user2` with both ids `5` and `6` but rather `6` and `7`.

This query returns all the unique `username, mood` pairs and whenever a duplicated pair is found it is discarded and the `id` with the minimum value from the duplicates is selected (guessed from the `User1, Sad` pair selection).

Comment: can you explain what is the difference between Group and Distinct?

Comment: Distinct is a simple concept: It will just select the rows in which all the values as a whole are unique. The group by, will make unique values for the grouped columns and for the non-grouped columns it will allow you to apply a function (in this case, the `min`inmum function) for all the values that are being put together. Probably a tutorial will explain it in more detail than a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

It's really unclear what you want, however one of these should hopefully help:

To get rows that are unique, use `DISTINCT`:

```
select distinct *
from mytable
```

To get only users that have only one mood:

```
select * from mytable
where id in (
    select id
    from mytable
    group by id
    having count(*) = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

> is there a SQL statement that could count the number of unique values in a certain column?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Username) FROM table1
```

> Is there a SQL statement that could return these unique values?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Username FROM table1
```

> If all of my wishes could come true I would like to take it even further, by querying for intersection unique values where both the Username and his mood

Well, you need beter wishes, but here you go:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Username, Mood FROM table1
```

I'm assuming your IDs are just illustrating record numbers and not necessary in the actual output.